# Angular need to sum the values of array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have data in which there are arrays. in the array, there is a value which is claimed_value. I need the sum of all claimed_value of arrays. an example I have array all have the claimed_value. but I need to sum of all the claimed_value which have the status=settled in the array.

this is how I'm calling the API.

```
getClaims(){
 if(this.userFilter.company_id){
 let url = 
  'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance- 
  api/get_claims.php?company_id='+this.userFilter.company_id;
 }else{
 let url = 
 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IGItakaful/insurance- 
 api/get_claims.php?offset=0&limit=200';
}
  this.clientData = this.httpClient.get(url).
  subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data.records;
  var status = 'settled';
  var status2 = 'submitted';


 var countsettled = this.data.filter((obj) => obj.status === 
 status).length;
 var countunsettled = this.data.filter((obj) => obj.status === 
 status2).length;


console.log(countsettled);
this.countsettled = countsettled;
console.log(countunsettled);
this.countunsettled = countunsettled;

  });

 }
```

[image]

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: as @CharybdeBE answer this is the sum of all claimed_value in array . but i want to add only array value which gave status = settled .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is more general `javascript`than angular

You can sum element of array by using the `Array.reduce` function

You can sum on a specific status by filtering first

Ie

```
const sum = this.data.filter(item => item.status === 'settled')
                     .reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.claimed_value), 0);
```

Note that as said in comment you received a `string` and not a `number`so you must convert it at first (see the `Number() function in the`reduce`closure)) otherwise the`+` operator will just concatenate the string

Comment: thanks i have updated my question i need the sum in which the status value is settled .

Comment: thanks but its showing wrong value its not sum the values

Comment: @UmaizKhan I see that in the data you have `claimed_value` is a string not a number so the `+` operator is concataining string, this can be fixed by transforming string to number (cf updat eof my post))

Answer (score 0):

```
let finalSum = 0;
this.data.forEach((item) => {
    if(item.status === 'settled'){
        finalSum += item.claimed_value
    }
}); 
console.log("final sum is ", finalSum);
```

Hello, This will loop on all the arrays in your data list , and add the number of `claimed_value` to the `finalSum` .
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: what is the value of sum ? i need to console the value of sum of values

Comment: the value of the sum here will be the finalSum , if you add console.log(finalSum) after the if statement , it will show the sum of all the arrays that has status = settled

Comment: its now showing the value its showing all the claimed_value which have status of settled . its not suming the values just showing all the array value which status is settled

Comment: I edited my answer, place the console after the loop and not after the if . just like my answer

Comment: yes its showing the value now . but the value of sum is showing wrong .

Comment: you want the sum of the submitted or settled ?

Comment: settled. But its not showing correct sum . because the value its show is less then 1 value of claimed_value so obviously the value is not correct .

Comment: `=+` is not the same as `+=`